# Multitape Turing Machine to accept power of 2 length 0's string?

Tags: turing-machines, strings, turing-recognizable, tape-complexity

I have been trying to find a multitape Turing Machine in order to accept a input string which consists on 0's and whose length is a power of 2:

[image]

However, Im getting troubble finding it, because I dont really know how to take the procedure with, for example, 2 tapes. I have found one solution for singletape, which is:

[image]

I have thought of 2 tapes. The first one will contain the contents of the 0's chain. The second tape will be used to copy the first half of the 0's of the first tape. In this way, every time we do this $copy$ process, we will make an analysis of the length of the resulting secondary string.

Comment: I don't understand your question. A one-tape solution also works as a two-tape solution: just ignore the second tape.

Comment: @orlp I know but the purpose of the exercise is to build another way so that I use 2 or more tapes

Comment: Note that using 2 tapes leads to a less elegant solution! However this simple approach should work: scan the first tape (input tape) and for each zero at odd position write a 0 on the second tape. If the length of the first string is odd **reject**. Otherwise the second tape contains exactly half of the zeors of the first one; check if the content of the second tape is exactly one 0, in this case **accept**. Otherwise copy the content of the second tape to the first one and "restart".